# Preserving or retrieving previous Camel exchange body

Tags: java, apache-camel

I'm on my first Camel project, so apologies if this is obvious or confusing.

The app is a simple service, happy path is to collect a PDF from a folder, obtain an email address to send it to, build and send the email (using a Velocity template, with the PDF as an attachment), record that the email was sent, and drop the file.

But I'm trying to build some retry logic, moving the files to separate folders to be reloaded later.

The issue I'm trying to solve is that the Velocity component overwrites the exchange-body with the email-body, and this email-body then replaces the PDF content if I then end a route with a File consumer component.

(I don't think I can use the 'move' parameter on the File *producer* component, as I am using two retry folders - I don't want to resend the email if a later step in the route fails.)

I can copy the file content to another part of the exchange, and then restore it before moving the file, but that feels rather scruffy to me. Is there a way of running the email components off a copy of the exchange, before resuming processing the file? Or some other way of obtaining an earlier version of the exchange body?

Comment: If you just want to move the PDF somewhere else so that when you have a failure you can access those files then multicast the message to a seda route and the velocity template route. This way both routes will have a copy of the message.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you just want to access the old message body to access the file object if the email sending is failed. 
If I'm right, you can store the file Object into the exchange property then you can access it whenever you want.

Comment: Thanks, I do mention that in my last para. But it is a bit awkward, as I would need to make sure it's restored and re-saved at different points in my routes. So I'm curious if it's a common problem with an established (better) solution.

Comment: Camel has a option to  useOriginalMessage in the dead letter http://camel.apache.org/dead-letter-channel.html, but it doesn't support other camel processor.